# Using GitLab Variables in a vanilla HTML page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab supports predefined environment variables, YAML-defined variables, and Secure User Variables - http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html

How can I use a secure user variable as part of a JavaScript script within a basic GitLab-Pages site?  (i.e. the site isn't using ruby, node, etc., it is using just html, css, & javascript)

For example, I have START_PAGE_USER and START_PAGE_ID variables defined for this [project](https://gitlab.com/metasean/start-up).  My [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/metasean/start-up/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) exposes them via `echo $START_PAGE_USER` & `echo $START_PAGE_ID`, and I have verified they are exposed in the build log.  How can I use those variables in my javascript (e.g. setting a username in my [config.js](https://gitlab.com/metasean/start-up/blob/master/src/scripts/config.js))):

```
var config = {
  user: typeof $START_PAGE_USER !== 'undefined' ? START_PAGE_USER : "Example User"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Project variables are for your testing enviroment. Not your code!
You cannot access those variables in you code.

As the [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html) said:

> When receiving a build from GitLab CI, the runner prepares the ***build environment***. It starts by setting a list of predefined variables (Environment Variables) and a list of user-defined variables

Comment: Since I ended up here: there is a neat little way you can get the env vars into your front end if you are using something like dotenv and a bundler. In your `gitlabl-ci.yml` include a script: `- echo "YOUR_VAR=$YOUR_VAR" >> .env`